# How to exclude some files using file::find::rule module using perl?

Tags: perl

I had tried to remove the files which ever named along with digits but it is not happening in my code.Here $output is my directory location.In which the directory contains multiple folders and sub folders.

From that folders and sub folders i want to pick my .ml files .In which the only the aplhabets named .ml files to be listed.

If the file names comes like(ev4.html,ev8.html and so on  it should be omitted).

Because here the file names comes along with the digits so i want to exclude the files which ever named along with digits and print the excepted output.

Here is my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find::Rule;
my $output="/home/location/radio/datas";
my @files=File::Find::Rule->file()
                ->name('*.ml')
                #->name(qr/\^ev\d+/)->prune->discard
                ->in($output);
for my $file(@files)
{
print "file:$file\n";
}
```

Obtained output:

```
file:/dacr/dacr.ml
file:/DV/DV.ml
file:DV/ev4/ev4.ml
```

Expected Output:

```
file:/dacr/dacr.ml
file:/DV/DV.ml
```

Comment: Your code is missing the `$output` variable. And you're talking about digits, but the only thing that's slightly related to numbers is commented out. Please [edit] and be more specific as to what you want to do.

Comment: Your English is hard to understand. Is that Google Translated? I think you mean: Do not include files with numbers in the name. Is that correct?

Comment: Your regex in the commented code wrong. I'll write an answer.

Comment: YES you are right @simbabque

Comment: And the `prune` is discarding everything. Give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt was almost correct, but your regular expression is wrong, and the `prune` and `discard` will remove all files, not only the ones for the regex.

```
my @files=File::Find::Rule->file()
    ->name('*.ml')
    ->name(qr/\^ev\d+/) # wrong regex
    ->prune->discard    # throws away all files
    ->in($output);
```

The correct regular expression to get files that contain any digit is simply `\d`. You are saying *a literal `^`, the letters `ev` and any number of digits, at least one*.

To make File::Find::Rule take all files that end in `.ml` and then not the ones that have a digit, use [`not`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule#not(-@rules-)).

```
my @files=File::Find::Rule->file()
    ->name('*.ml')
    ->not( File::Find::Rule->name(qr/\d/) )
    ->in($output);
```

This will get all `.ml` files, and discard any file that has any digit in the name.